# How do I do URL redirection in OpenACS / AOLServer?

Tags: url, redirect, openacs

We have a page with a form in OpenACS, and we'd like to redirect users to an external site/URL containing a totally different page/form.

How is it best done (on either the OpenACS-side or AOLServer-side)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With OpenACS, here are some suggestions, starting with util_httppost:

http://openacs.org/forums/message-view?message_id=17963

I don't have privs to post more than one hyperlink, but inside this one there are links to other posts that discuss ns_returnredirect or just Javascript on the front end as a possible solution.

Comment: I'm afraid the requirement is much simpler than that -- it's really just a mere URL redirection.  Preferably invisible to the user.

Comment: then maybe Javascript on the page is more what you need?  That way you won't have to hack with either AOLserver or OpenACS...

Comment: I can no longer verify if any of the OpenACS answers work.  I vaguely remember that my colleague who used to work on this chose the JavaScript redirect solution, so I'm accepting this answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say go with ad_returnredirect http://openacs.org/api-doc/proc-view?proc=ad_returnredirect
It's recommended over ns_returnredirect for the reasons described on the API link.

Answer (score 1):

This an example, I hope this will be usefull for you:

```
ad_form -name form1 -form {

    ....

} -after_submit {

      ad_returnredirect -allow_complete_url "http://www.google.com/"
}
```